# Your bundle is locked to activesupport (7.0.8) from rubygems repository but that version can no longer be found in that source

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods, bundle

I have a react-native application which has a Gemfile. I have a post-install script which would run after `npm install` has a command `bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios/`. It is working absolutely well till today but suddenly it is throwing an error like ***Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.*** I tried with the `bundle install` but it is throwing the below error.

**Your bundle is locked to activesupport (7.0.8) from rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally, but that version can no longer be found in that source. That
means the author of activesupport (7.0.8) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a version other than activesupport (7.0.8) that hasn't been removed in order to
install.**

I should not remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` because many changes are getting introduced.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1 ( If you are using asdf):**

This issue is due to incorrect global ruby version. Currently it is set to 2.6.1 but it is expecting 3.X version to work as expected. I am using asdf for tool management and It just requires to add `export PATH="$HOME/.asdf/shims:$PATH"` to `.zshrc`. Then run `bundle install` and it will install the dependencies without any issue.

**Solution 2:**

I have removed Gemfile.lock from the repo and re-run the `bundle install` again. It worked without any issues. Also, later I run the `bundle exec pod install` and it worked as well without any issues.